# Dart const - type '_UnmodifiableSet<Map<String, double>>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, double>'

Tags: flutter, dart

Writing a flutter app with Bloc. A pattern that is used often in examples is using const constructors for state objects so that they're immutable. One of the properties in my state is a Map<string, double> and I'm having trouble initializing this as a const. The error is:

`type '_UnmodifiableSet<Map<String, double>>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, double>'`

Here is the class constructor that is throwing the error:

```
class MyState extends Equatable {
  final List<Popup> popups;
  final Map<String, double> distance;

  const MyState ([
    popups = const <Popup>[],
    distance = const <Map<String, double>>{}
  ]) : this.popups = popups, this.distance = distance;
```

If MyState is initialized without a value for `distance` I want it to be an empty object. The list initializer `Popup` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should help you understand (how to specify hash maps creation):

```
void main() {
  Map<String, double> distance;
  distance = Map<String, double>();
  distance = const <String, double>{};
}
```

P.S.

Your code in incorrect.

P.S. P.S.

This (your) code specifies the creation of hash set.

```
void main() {
  final set = <Map<String, double>>{};
  print(set.runtimeType);
}
```

Result:

```
_CompactLinkedHashSet<Map<String, double>>
```

That is `Set` of `<Map<String, double>` (`Set<Map<String, double>>`).